# jQuery Mobile List View: Refresh from other page

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

So say I'm in page #home and I'm populating a `<ul>` in #page1 with `<li>'`s I inject dynamically. I want to refresh the jquery mobile list view before I transition to it, but when I try to do that it tells me that I can't refresh something that hasn't been initialized. So I try to just do     `$("#somediv ul").listview();` but that doesn't work either. The only way it works is if I changePage to #page1 ..but when I do that there's an ugly lag while it refreshes.

How can I get around this?

Comment: have you tried `$("#somediv ul").listview('refresh');`

Comment: actually above comment throws the same error. i have put the example in this fiddle can you check whether it is matching with your problem or not http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/KNyNb/

Comment: @dhaval ya thats exactly my problem

Comment: do you find the same lag in the demo also??

Comment: not sure what you mean by lag... but i opened the console on that fiddle and it said the same thing as mine.. but for mine, I'm not just appending an item I'm replacing the entire inner HTML of the <ul>. Either way, when I call the refresh my program doesn't proceed to the next line.

Comment: O..lol I'm the one who definted a lag...sorry um one sec let me check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8880/discussion-between-joshdg-and-dhaval)

Comment: OK so ..no, I don't get a lag....but if you open the console there's still an error so if I want to change pages programatically after the 'refresh' line, it wont get there ... (and its not in my case)

Comment: Like if you add alert('foo') before the refresh then alert('bar') after it, the second wont fire

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

$( '#somediv ul' ).trigger( 'updatelayout' );